# Is there a way to control the event in fullcalendar when it's dragged to the same day?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the editable resource in FullCalendar and it's working very well when I drag the event to another day, but when I just don't want to drag the event anymore and drag it to the same day it was before, all of the other events become disabled and I can't drag any of them.

Could you, please, help me?

Here is my code

````
editable: true,
eventDrop: function(info){
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo _Z_URL_ . $pkgnm; ?>control.php",
      data: {
        action: 'change_date',
        age_id: info.event.id,
        age_data: info.event.start.toLocaleString(),
        age_end: info.event.end.toLocaleString(),
      },
      success: function(data){
        if(data >= 1){
          toastr.success('<?php echo constant("A data do evento foi alterada com sucesso!"); ?>',                 '<?php echo constant("Informação!"); ?>', {"closeButton": true, "timeOut": "2000"});
          window.setTimeout(function () {
          }, 2000);
        } else if(data === '-1'){
            toastr.error('<?php echo constant("O sistema encontrou um registro com esse recurso no mesmo horário!"); ?>', '<?php echo constant("Erro!"); ?>', {"closeButton": true, "timeOut": "2000"});
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                  window.location = "<?php echo _Z_URL_ . $pkgnm; ?>";
            }, 2000);
                        } else if(data === '-2'){
                            toastr.error('<?php echo constant("Não é possível alterar a data de um evento que não é seu!"); ?>', '<?php echo constant("Erro!"); ?>', {"closeButton": true, "timeOut": "2000"});
                            window.setTimeout(function () {
                                window.location = "<?php echo _Z_URL_ . $pkgnm; ?>";
                            }, 2000);
                        } else {
                            toastr.error('<?php echo constant("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar o registro!"); ?>', '<?php echo constant("Erro!"); ?>', {"closeButton": true, "timeOut": "2000"});
                            window.setTimeout(function () {
                                window.location = "<?php echo _Z_URL_ . $pkgnm; ?>";
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    }
                })
            }, ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

You just have to add the `dragRevertDuration: 0,` after the code `editable:true,` to fix this error!